# Drawing stripes in OpenGL (C++)

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, glut

I'm following the xoax.net tutorials for OpenGL in C++, and I am stuck on drawing the stripes in the U.S. flag using a for loop. I just get a blue screen (since I set the background colour to blue). Here is the code for the 'DrawStripes' function:

```
void DrawStripes() {
for (int x = 0; x < 13; ++x) {
    if (x % 2 == 0) {
        glColor3f(204/255, 0, 0);
    } else {
        glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
    }

    float fStartX = 0;
    float fEndX = 1;
    float fStartY = x * (1/13);
    float fEndY = (x + 1) * (1/13);

    if (x > 5) {
        fStartX = .76/1.9;
    }
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(fStartX, fStartY, 0);
    glVertex3f(fEndX, fStartY, 0);
    glVertex3f(fEndX, fEndY, 0);
    glVertex3f(fStartX, fEndY, 0);
    glEnd();
    }
}
```

(I have put this function in the 'draw' function so it isn't just I'm not telling it to use the function)
Any ideas?

--- EDIT ---
Here are the 'Draw' and 'Initialize' functions:

```
void Draw() {
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    DrawStripes();
    glFlush();
}

void Initialize() {
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? What kind of result do you get with this code?

Comment: As I say in the question, I just get a blue screen (since I set the background colour to blue)

Comment: Post more of your code. How do you set up the model-view-projection matrices?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I read your question to quickly. If you drop the for-lopp, are you able to draw a single line?

Comment: oh, ok i was wondering what 'f' after it does! thanks :) make an answer out of it and ill accept

Comment: You should be aware that learning to use the fixed-function pipeline as a beginner in 2013 is not a good move. See http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Fixed_Function_Pipeline. OpenGL is evolving, but old OpenGL articles  don't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1/13 is 0 in C++. Been there, done that. For float constants you want to use 1.0f/13.0f.

Comment: Good catch. Also `204/255` will result in the value 0, so the color will be black instead of a tint of red.

Comment: You need only to have one float operand: 1/13. is enough.

Comment: Problem is that it can become voodoo programming (extranneous f's and .0) for the OP if he doesn't take the time to really understand why he's doing this.